# Remove focus from a text field Objective C Xcode

Tags: objective-c, focus, uitextfield, uipickerview

In my app I have a text field, that when clicked, a picker view  appears.
I want the focus to be removed from the field when I click done on the picker view because currently if I hit done then click the same text field the picker view won't appear again (say if user hits done by accident and wants to edit field again). 
Please help, thanks

Comment: `[textField resignFirstResponder]` ?? what do you mean by focus?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the firstResponder to another UI item.

Assuming that the tag of the textField is set and that you want it to transfer the firstResponder(focus) to another text field which has a tag this is what you can do in the code where you are handling the done button click

```
    NSInteger next_TextField_Tag = 202;
    UIResponder *nextResponder = ["current_TextView_Here".superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
```

This will make sure that the same text box is not the first responder when the user has finished clicking done.

You can set the tag to a particular textField like this

```
YOUR_TextField_Here.tag=x;
```

Comment: How if I don't have anything else to become first responder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code 
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];